# Помогите прописать RewriteRule в .htaccess (MVC)

Tags: .htaccess, apache-modules

Url:

```
http://example.com/search
http://example.com/search/?data=something&another_data=something&another_data=something...
http://example.com/search/?data=something&another_data=something&another_data=something.../page_3
```

Правила:

```
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?url=user/search [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ index.php?url=user/search/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/page_([0-9]+)(/?)$ index.php?url=user/search/$1/$2 [L]
```

Работает лишь первое правило.

Answer (score 0):

Логично, что не работает.

`RewriteRule` работает с URI в виде "путей к файлам", если кратко. В первом случае `uri` равен **search**, во втором и третьем **search/**. Именно это придет на вход RewriteRule.

Всё, что после знака **?** - это аргументы (`args`).

Поэтому без `RewriteCond` здесь не обойтись.

Для второго запроса:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?url=user/search/%1 [R,L]
```

Для третьего:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\/page_([0-9])+$
RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?url=user/search/%1/%2 [R,L]
```

Итого:

```
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?url=user/search [R,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?url=user/search/%1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\/page_([0-9])+$
RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?url=user/search/%1/%2 [R,L]
```